# WPF: How to access specific DataTable from a different window

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am creating a WPF Application that has 2 windows.

In Window_1 i have a button that imports an excel document and stores corresponding fields in a DataTable. After this excel document has been successfully imported i want to prompt user to view the document. If the user says 'Yes' then Window_2 is loaded.

In Window_2 there is a DataGrid and i want it to be populated using the DataTable in Window_1?

How do i populate the DataGrid in Window_2 using data stored in the DataTable in Window_1

Comment: create a property in `Window_2` : `public DataTable ExcelData {get;set;}` and when user says 'Yes', assign value to that property: `var w2 = new Window_2 { ExcelData = myData };`

Comment: ASh, this is what i was looking for. Thank you thank you. It worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i have found a solution to my problem. (I have derived this solution from ASh's response.)

In Window_1

```
DataTable maindata = new DataTable(); //datatable with imported excel data

//button click event to prompt user to view Window_2
private void yes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
var w2 = new Window { dt = maindata };
w2.Show();
}
```

In Window_2

```
public DataTable dt { get; set; }

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView; //dtGrid is the DataGrid
}
```

So here is what i think.

Upon click 'Yes' (yes_Click) the data in maindata DataTable is equated to the data in dt DataTable (present in Window_2). The latter DataTable gets the data of maindata DataTable and loads it into DataGrid dt.

I thought i should put out my findings in case another person runs into the same problem.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the data from window 1 to window 2 like this:

```
var data = //your data;
Window_2 window = new Window_2(data);
window.Show();

//then in window 2

public Window_2(var data){
    InitializeComponent();
    this._fieldWithData = data; 
}
```

So make a constructor overload where you pass the data. Then you can pass through the data from the different windows. StackOverflow is here to help to figure out on how to actually fill the datagrids, plenty of posts about that! Hope that helps!

Comment: Derp thank you for your response. Your code makes sense to me but somehow i am failing to get expected results. I have used ASh's solution and it worked

Comment: No problem :) glad you found an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is the version of the code that works for me in a similar scenario.

In the first Window, in .xaml.cs I would place this:

```
DataTable myDataTable=new DataTable();
//fill in myDataTable with anything you want. Your case is Excel data

private void btnExtractComplementaryBOM_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ShowDataGrid window2 = new ShowDataGrid(myTable) ; //open up an instance of an existing Window called ShowDataGrid. Pass to it as an argument the dataTable object which embeds data from your Excel
  ShowDataGrid.Show();
}
```

In the second Window  (which can be customized as you wish by its .xaml).
You should have  the following lines of code in  ShowDataGrid.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ShowDataGrid : Window //2nd Window is called "ShowDataGrid" here
{
    public DataTable dataTable2; //declare a public datatable variable

    public ShowDataGrid(DataTable dataTable2) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        datagridName.ItemsSource = dataTable2.DefaultView;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From one window you can get the other window by name, then get the datagrid by name (as long as you have named everything).

```
Window w = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "windowname");

DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)w.FindName("datagridname");
```

Then 'dg' is a reference to the datagrid that you want.